# How can I keep the text of the loader static?

Tags: html, css

I have one circle loader and one text inside. How can I keep this text inside the circle static? Because it's moving with the circle. My simple code is:

```
<div class="loader">
  <div class="stop">
    STOP
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.loader {
   border-radius: 50%;
   border-top: 8px solid red;
   border-bottom: 8px solid red;
   border-right:8px solid red;
   border-left:8px solid white;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
   margin:220px;
}

.stop{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size:20px;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Any idea fellows!!??

Comment: You are rotating the whole div so the content of the div will also rotate.

Answer (score 1):

Just added a block element to hold both divs and only animating the loader div with circle, so the text div remains static

```css
.loader-block {
  position: relative;
  margin:50px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
.loader {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border-top: 8px solid red;
   border-bottom: 8px solid red;
   border-right:8px solid red;
   border-left:8px solid white;   
   animation: spin 4s linear infinite;   
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stop{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size:20px;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-block">
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <div class="stop">STOP</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you a lot. I write the same with the other man above. You made it looks so simple!! It's incredible!! Thanks again.

Comment: @kostas If your question is answered, tick the answer you found useful

Comment: and how can I tick the answer? I don't know, I'm new member of the site.

Comment: @kostas you should see a tick icon (grey'ed  out) under the up/down votes, click that tick once and it turns green

Answer (score 0):

As @this.Believer was saying, the whole div is rotating rather than the loader. You will need to create a separate element for the rotating circle, then position the .stop element:

HTML

```
<div class="loaderFrame">
  <div class="stop">STOP</div>
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.loaderFrame {
   position: relative;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   margin:220px;
}

.loader {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border-top: 8px solid red;
   border-bottom: 8px solid red;
   border-right:8px solid red;
   border-left:8px solid white;
   animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
}

.stop{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size:20px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84ueo343/)

Comment: thank you very much @thisiskelvin. You made it looks so simple. Thanks again. Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
    <div class="loader">
    </div>
   <!--removed below div from loader -->  
   <div class="stop">
        STOP
    </div>
```

and css

```
.stop{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 32%; //set this according to ur requirement
  width: 100%;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Comment: appreciate your effort but this isn't a great solution, as the left and top position needs changing depending on the screensize/device width

Comment: ofcourse it is to be done .. and i guess this is to be understood

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that div class="stop" is within the div class="loader", and so get's it's spin (as a child div get's it's positioning from it's parent.)

Solution is to make stop and loader siblings instead.

you could try something like this (you'll need to fiddle around with the width's / height etc, but you get the idea)

```
.loader {
   border-radius: 50%;
   border-top: 8px solid red;
   border-bottom: 8px solid red;
   border-right:8px solid red;
   border-left:8px solid white;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
   margin:220px auto;
}

.stop{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:280px auto;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="loader">
    </div>

    <div class="stop">
      STOP
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/wnpb8hwp/1/#&togetherjs=CAar1kqum2

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .loader {
            animation: 4s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
            border-color: red red red white;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 8px;
            height: 120px;
            margin: auto;
            width: 120px;
        }

        .stop {
            font-size: 20px;
            left: 45%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 55px;
            width: 100px;
        }

        @keyframes spin {
            0% {
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }

            100% {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        .loaderblock
         {
             position:relative
         }
```

```html
<div class="loaderblock">
    <div class="loader">
    </div>
    <div class="stop">
        STOP
    </div>
</div>
```